# Flask/SQLalchemy/Jinja2 -- nested loop rendering

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am a beginner to Flask. I am building a simple quiz application. I have two tables. One is question table and the other is options table with one right answer. I wanted to show one question and four options, then second question and so on.
I searched every where on how to render into the template. Stuck a road block. Tried different lazy options.

```
Model.py
class Question(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'edu_word_questions'
question_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
word = db.Column(db.String(100))
question_type = db.Column(db.String(100))
answers = db.relationship('Question_answers', backref='Question',
                            lazy='subquery')

class Question_answers(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'edu_question_answers'
answer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
answer = db.Column(db.String(100))
question_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('edu_word_questions.question_id'))

routes.py
@app.route('/quiz')
def quiz():
  quiz = db.session.query(Question, Question_answers).join(Question_answers,Question.question_id == Question_answers.question_id)
# quiz = db.session.query(Question).all()
# answers = db.session.query(Question_answers).all()
return render_template('quiz.html', quiz=quiz)

HTML 
{% for key,value in quiz %}
 <li><h2>{{ word }}</h2>
 <li><h2>{{ answer }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your loop didn't quite make sense as it was not an dictionary. Since you have answers in the questions, you can just grab the questions, and automically grab the answers at runtime as it is lazy loaded when you iterate through q.answers in your template.

routes.py

```
@app.route('/quiz')
def quiz():
    questions = db.session.query(Question).all()
    return render_template('quiz.html', questions=questions )
```

HTML

```
{% for q in questions %}
 <li><h2>{{ q.word }}</h2>
    {% for a in q.answers %}
        <li><h2>{{ a.answer }}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Yes, it took care of my mess. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Chambana glad I could help. If it answered your question, please tick it as accepted answer to the left.